# Java Swing JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have created customized Button. For that i have overrided paintComponenet method. How can I set Button Text on such button? I tried doing it using drawString method. But which x,y values should i give? (g.drawString("button text",x,y)). Please till me if anyone has handled this.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    DefaultButtonModel bmodel = (DefaultButtonModel) super.getModel();

    Image im = (new ImageIcon("image")).getImage();
    System.out.println("im is "+im.getSource());
    System.out.println("widthis" + im.getWidth(this));
    int imageX = (getWidth() - im.getWidth(this)) /2;
    int imageY = (getHeight() - im.getHeight(this)) / 2;
    if(!super.isEnabled()) {
        System.out.println("in disabled");
        g.drawImage(disabled, imageX, imageY, this);
       g.drawString( super.getText(), super.getX(),(int) (super.getY() / (1.9)));
    }
    else {
        if(bmodel.isPressed()) {
           System.out.println("in pressed");
            g.drawImage(down, imageX, imageY, this); 
        } else if(bmodel.isRollover()) {
            System.out.println("in roll overed");
            g.drawImage(highlight, imageX, imageY, this);
        } else if(bmodel.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("in enabled");
            g.drawImage(normal, imageX, imageY, this);
        } else {
            System.out.println("in else");
            g.drawImage(normal, imageX, imageY, this);
        }
        g.drawString( super.getText(), super.getX(),(int) (super.getY() / (2.5)));
    }



}
```

Comment: Why do you take so much trouble? Why don't you use an IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse etc)?

Comment: Prasoon? What does an IDE have to do with custom-written Swing controls?

Comment: @JOhannes: Nothing, but it would be easier for him to design a GUI with the help of an IDE, however he needs to know the basics.

Comment: Haven't seen a Java IDE so far that actually helps with implementing custom controls.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call `super(g)` on the first line of paintComponent method and use the `setText` method to change the string on the button.

Something like this:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   super.paintComponent(g);
   // do your customized painting here...
}
```

Comment: super(g) is giving me error.."call to super must be first statement of the constructor"

Comment: sorry, it should have been super.paintComponent(g);

Comment: That's the ticket - to paint background reverse and do custom painting first.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do, you never stated the actual requirement? It looks like you are trying to draw text on top of the image. If so, then there is no need for custom painting, just use:

```
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
button.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
```

You can set rollover and pressed icons as needed.